# What happens if you destroy every Crimson Heart, Shadow Orb and/or Crimson/Demon Altar?

Tags: terraria

I'm not exactly sure about what happens if you destroy every Crimson Heart, Shadow Orb and/or Demon/Crimson Altar? My guess is that it stops Corruption/Crimson from spreading.

Also, how do you destroy EVERY PIECE OF CRIMSON?

Comment: Just to be clear, destroying Altars and Hearts/Orbs does little to stop the spread of corruption. They spread as long as there are corruptible tiles within 4 tile range from any corrupted elements including corrupted vines and Ebonstone. These items are usually located inside the corruption itself and rarely contributes to the spreading.

Comment: I tried to help you rephrase your question better but should clarify the last part yourself. If you are asking how to purify/remove the entire Crimson/Corruption, there are already many questions with answer about that. You should be able to find your answer from one of them.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Terraria Wiki, there isn't a special consequence of destroying all altars or orbs. Only the normal things are happening like the chance of spawning a meteroite or the increase of one hardmode ore amount like Titanium.
There is also this information:

> If all corruption/crimson and hallow blocks are purified, then when speaking to the Dryad about the world status, she will say "[name of world] is completely pure. You have done an amazing job!".
>   http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption

But I don't know if it will spawn again. It is a waste of time to try it, because you need items and lore from there and when your world is in hardmode, the corruption/crimson is spread anywhere from the surface to the hell. It is a huge amount of work to pure it.

Comment: Corruption/Crimson can respawn by smashing Demon Altars. Every time you smash one, there is a 2-in-3 chance that a single stone block in the Caverns level will corrupt and likely start spreading.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confuse if you are referring to [Crimson/Demon Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar), [Crimson Heart](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Heart)/[Shadow Orb](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb) or [Crimson](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson)/[Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption) itself. I'll cover all.

**[Crimson/Demon Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar)**

It is actually beneficial to destroy these since each will give you mode hardmode ores in the world. But it is also required to make items such as [Night's Edge](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Night%27s_Edge). Destroying every last [Altar](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar) will making obtaining such items impossible in this world. I suggest leaving the one closest to your base untouched. You can isolate it buy digging a 4 tile wide gap between it and any other tiles and even box it up with incorruptible tiles such as [Grey Brick](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gray_Brick) to prevent it from spreading corruption.

**[Crimson Heart](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Heart)/[Shadow Orb](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Orb)**

Each of this destroyed will drop some items and also gives a chance to spawn [Meteorite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_(biome)). Also every 3 destroyed will spawn the respective biome boss [Brain of Cthulhu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brain_of_Cthulhu) or [Eater of Worlds](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eater_of_Worlds). Therefore the only significant result of breaking every one of these is the possibility that there will be many [Meteorites](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_(biome)) in your world. Assuming the boss will not kill you there is no other significant penalties for doing so.

**[Crimson](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Crimson)/[Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption)**

To remove the entire of these biomes especially in hardmode plus having all/most [Altars](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Altar) destroyed is going to be lots of work, but assuming you actually did, a lot of monsters and plants will not longer spawn in this world until the biomes are introduced again. This includes useful items such as Ebonkoi which is a fish only obtainable in [Corruption](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption) for making [Wrath Potion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wrath_Potion) that gives 10% damage - very important in later bosses.

Monsters such as [Dark Mummy](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mummy), [Crimson/Corrupted Mimic](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mimic) also becomes unavailable which removes that possibility of obtaining powerful items such as [Dao of Pow](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dao_of_Pow) and [Daedalus Stormbow](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Daedalus_Stormbow). Though Mimics can still be spawned if you already have the [Key of Night](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Key_of_Night).

Overall, I will not suggest entirely removing the biomes, simply isolating them to prevent spreading will be.